Using docker secrets correct
I'm trying to find a secure way to store API-tokens, login credentials etc. I use them in docker containers and don't want to store them in my docker compose or as env variables that can be read out as clear strings.
I want to use docker secrets but I don't know how to pass all the sensitive data automaticlly because I have to store them as plain text somewhere in order to pass the data to docker secrets.
I had the idea of creating a simple Python script that creates passwords and pass the output to docker secrets.
